Is there a symbol for the Hyper key?
I was wondering if there is a well-known symbol for the Hyper key?
I found ✦ ("BLACK FOUR POINTED STAR" U+2726) used on wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-cadet_keyboard but no comments were provided in the edit about why it was a black four pointed star in particular.

Is this a question about Macintosh computers or keyboards that have a dedicated hyper key (and not a combination of keys)?

It's a question about whether there is a known symbol for the dedicated Hyper key that exists on some keyboards, and where it's coming from. I'm guessing it also applies to whether there's a known symbol for the combination of keys used as the logical modifier "hyper"

For context, the WP revision in question was a blanket switch to the “Key top” template, which was created in 2015 with the pointed star as the Hyper symbol (and no explanation).

Not to be confused with the hyperspace button on a Spacewar! gamepad.

@StephenKitt This is important, since the keyboard only have the keys marked with the text 'HYPER'. Symbols are only used on the alpha numerical keys.

@UncleBod indeed, and that would be worth mentioning in the question — I’m not aware of any keyboard with a Hyper key and a symbol for it (unlike Meta which used a diamond, or more accurately a rotated square, on Sun keyboards). It’s possible the association with the four-pointed star is a Wikipedia invention.

None of the modifier keys have symbols marked on the keys.  All of them have weird symbols on the wikipedia writeup. None adds any explanatory value. Apparently wikipedia made them all up.

What research is done by the author of the question? How many keyboards with a 'hyper' key are known? What do those look like?

@StephenKitt indeed, the symbol was introduced in the first version of the "Key top" template on Wikipedia by Crissov.
Since some key tops do not have a symbol, I was assuming that it was coming from somewhere

Same here, the only time I know of a Hyper key being explicit named that would be the Space Cadet one which spelled out the name. Software expecting a Hyper key on other keyboards/machines usually repurposed an existing key or key combination

@MathieuDutour Crissov is apparently still very active on Wikipedia and seems knowledgeable in several areas of writing systems and tech standards. He's also on GitHub. You can probably ask him for more details on his Wikipedia talk page.

@UncleBod I'm unaware of any Mac keyboard with a hyper key.

It’s difficult to prove a negative, but nevertheless I think it’s fair to say that no, the Hyper key doesn’t have a symbol. It wasn’t present on many keyboards; the two I’m aware of are the Space Cadet and the “simplified” Symbolics keyboard, both designed by Symbolics for use with Lisp Machines. These spelled out all their modifier keys on the keycaps (Ctrl, Shift, Meta etc.).
The only modifier keys with common symbols are Shift with the large arrow ⇧, arguably Meta which was represented as ◆ on Sun keyboards, and the Mac-specific ⌥ Option and ⌘ Command keys. Ctrl is often represented using a caret, ^, but I’m not aware of many keyboards actually using that (perhaps unsurprisingly since the caret itself typically appears on a key, used to produce a caret or a circumflex accent). The other symbols used on modifier keys in Wikipedia’s “Key top” template (created in 2015) aren’t generally used and might well be Wikipedia inventions.

Can confirm that option and command as depicted on that Wikipedia page have been present on Mac keyboards for most of its 40-year history, including presently, and are often used in documents (as well as on-screen to communicate shortcuts in pull-down menus). Though they're Mac things, so I guess it depends on your definition of 'common'.

Fair point @Tommy, I should mention those.

Microsoft use ✲ for Ctrl on their keyboards. I work in a place with mostly Surface laptops and I see it on pretty much all varieties of external keyboards in use. It's not used anywhere except on the keyboards, but it's common nonetheless. And not to mention, there's the Windows logo for the "Windows" (AKA meta) key.

@BenjaminPenney the symbol on the Ctrl key is news to me! I’ve found a few pictures of Microsoft keyboards with that symbol, but it seems to only have been used on a small selection of models, and AFAICT none of the keyboards currently sold by Microsoft feature it. I’ve never seen one in person! As far as the Windows key is concerned, I left it out because it’s mostly used as an action key, not a modifier key.

It's not a small selection. It's most commonly found on the ergonomic line. As far as why you can't find such keyboards sold by Microsoft, that's because MS stopped selling them in 2023 and are they're due to be launched under the Incase brand as "Incase designed by Microsoft". https://www.incase.com/cdn/shop/files/L3V-Sculpt_Comfort_Desktop-WEB-B-104.png?v=1732570599&width=700 https://www.incase.com/pages/incase-designed-by-microsoft I'm not sure what distinction you are making between a modifier and an action key. My point was that the Windows and Apple-specific keys map to Meta.

Lisp machine modifier keys had abbreviations rather than symbols.
From to the Symbolics, Inc. Lisp Machines Summary 3600 Edition (August 1983), page 2:

Modifier kets are designed to be held down while pressing other keys. They do not themselves transmit characters.  A combined keystroke like META-X is pronounced "meta x" and written as m-X.  This notation means press the META key and, while holding it down, press the X key.
Modifier keys are abbreviated as follows:
Key     Abbreviation
CTRL    c-
META    m-
SUPER   s-
HYPER   h-
SHIFT   sh-


Those abbreviations live on in EMACS.

In GNU Emacs shift is S- not sh-

well, sh-it.  (lowercase) s- is still super, CTRL/META/HYPER/SHIFT are (uppercase) C-, M-, H-, S- respectively.

Emacs = Escape Meta Alt Control Shift (or Super?). Somehow Hyper didn't make it into the acronym. ;-)

This does not seem to attempt to answer the question.

@LeoB. True, not a direct answer, but it gives a hint of how people communicated about that key. Information the question is missing.

@PaŭloEbermann it does when Sean Connery says it ;-)
